# How do I set up a dropbox?

Tags: php, dropbox

Hi guys my company requires that we set up in our application a dropbox feature kinda like what we see in highrise implemented. The idea is that when an account is created - automatically for each user a dropbox 'email' would be created and users would send emails to that dropbox address and based upon the email teh content would be added to the system as a post, a task, or a note, or even as an attachment.

How are dropboxes like this set up automatically - I'm using php here?

EDIT ======

I'll try to elaborate.

A dropbox in the sense that lets say a user is created at my website. He would be given an email id of the kind:

```
dropbox@[someuser id].mywebsite.com
```

He could then send an email using any email program to the address and the contents of this email would end up in his account. Think of being able to add a blog post by sending an email. Thats the idea I need to work on.

Comment: Do you have a specific bit of code that you need help with? This sounds like you want us to give you a pretty huge chunk of code.

Comment: Errm, are you using "dropbox" in its convetional sense (at your location)?  Or in the sense of https://www.dropbox.com/?    I only ask because https://www.dropbox.com/ is not exactly email oriented.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to set up a catch all email address - then setup a pipe to a PHP file which will extract the account ID from the 'to' email address and handle everything else (extracting the attachment, inserting the data to the database).

I've done this before, so if you've got anything specific, let me know, but it's fairly simple to set up.

Comment: How do I set up a pipe? and catch all email addresses? I think Thats what I'm not getting at i.e the creation of email addresses of this order dynamically - I'm assuming that emaila ddresses are checked by cron jobs in the back ground.